# how to reopen a post closed as duplicate to a canonical

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I've asked a question about food storage-lifetime: [for how long can I store homemade chocolate mousse in the fridge?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/113559/for-how-long-can-i-store-homemade-chocolate-mousse-in-the-fridge)

initially I wrote

> My chocolate mousse recipe includes just raw eggs (2 weeks until best
> before date), butter, sugar and black chocolate.

which I suppose got me the question closed by a moderator as a duplicate

Now, I've edited the question pointing out that the ingredients in question (eggs) get transformed, since they get in contact with the hot chocolate, hence heated up.

So in my opinion, the canonical doesn't answer the question anymore. How do I get the answer re-opened?

Answer (score 3):

As Stephie said, the procedure for reopening is the same.

I must however mention that the question on "how long does it last" is a rather special case. In fact, the canonical answer was written in such a way that it covers basically all possible cases out there. * So when you believe that your case is not cover because of , this typically means that  is not relevant for determining the food safety classification of your food.

We get this happening all the time, since people rarely understand how the label "safe" is applied in food safety, and tend to mistake it for the actual risk of getting sick (or not). For anybody interested, we have described the actual rules in https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info. I cannot stress enough that they are meant to be applied absolutely literally, and to be just as broad as they are stated. I know it looks like a big wall of text, but most questions by people who ask without knowing them tend to get closed - and because of the huge number, we don't have the capacity to re-explain the reason to everybody personally. We can only hope that reading them will save people the effort of making irrelevant edits which have no chance of getting the question reopened.

---

* OK, it is impossible to cover 100% of all possible special cases, but it covers so many of them that the possibility that somebody asks one of them is miniscule - and the moderators and high-rep users tend to know them and don't close as duplicate in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The procedure is exactly the same as for every other duplicate:

> Questions that are edited within five days of being closed **are automatically added to a reopening queue for community review**. Closed questions can also be nominated for reopening by a user with sufficient reputation. If enough community members agree, the question will be reopened and can accept answers.

(From the [Help Center](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).)

In short, the post will be reopened if multiple community members with the corresponding privilege or a moderator (with a binding vote) vote for it to be reopened, it will be presented in the review queue automatically.

I *personally* won’t vote for reopening, as a classic Mousse au Chocolat (and your list of ingredients and somewhat vague description seems to hint at that) is not heated enough to qualify as “cooked protein”, especially the whites are nowhere near pasteurization temperature. So still covered by the “uncooked protein -> eggs out of shell” entry. The community may vote as they see fit.